# Az cli to reset the service principal without overwriting

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli, service-principal

Through az cli I am getting "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation"
while trying  to append the service principal without overwriting where as through azure portal I can append new secret. Is the below command correct?

az ad sp credential reset --display-name  --id xxxxxxxxxxxxxx --append --years 1
Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Answer (score 0):

The error *"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation"* usually occurs if you don't have sufficient **roles** or **permissions** to perform the operation.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have one service principal with one existing secret named **`new`** like below:

[image]

I used below **CLI command** to connect my Azure account:

```
az login --allow-no-subscriptions --only-show-errors
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran same command as you to add secret, I got **same error** as you like below:

```
az ad sp credential reset --display-name --id xxxxxxxxxxxxxx --append --years 1
```

[image]

To **resolve** the error, I assigned `Application Administrator` role to the user like below:

[image]

Now, I logged in with above user credentials again and ran **below modified command** to add secret:

```
az ad app credential reset --display-name secret --id <appID> --append --years 1
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where I can see both old and new secrets successfully like below:

[image]

In your case, check how you are signing to your account from **CLI** and make sure to have **proper** directory role like `Application Administrator` to add secret in application.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried to add the application administrator role under roles and administrators but I don't see its getting popped when I search in the box. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Could you include what Azure AD roles you currently have on your tenant?

Comment: Please check these 
**[prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/manage-roles-portal#prerequisites)** before assigning directory role to user.